# Error writing xlsx in R: Could not initialize class sun.java2d.Disposer

Tags: java, javascript, r

I'm using the xlsx package to write Excel files in R:

```
addPicture('trend_indirect.png' ,sheet1)
addDataFrame(df.ssis_duplmonth ,sheet1, startRow=22)
addDataFrame(df.ssis_dupltrans ,sheet1, startRow=35)

addDataFrame(df.ssis_duplmonth_dir, sheet2, startRow=22)
addDataFrame(df.ssis_dupltrans_dir, sheet2, startRow=55)



saveWorkbook(wb, file="SSIS_import_controls.xlsx")
```

At this point I get the following error:

```
> addDataFrame(df.ssis_duplmonth ,sheet1, startRow=22)
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Z", "hasField", .jcast(x, "java/lang/Object"),  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.java2d.Disposer
```

R version 2.15.2, 32bit.
Thanks

Edit: I can't really make it reproducible as probably the issue is in my settings but I get the error when I run this:

> library('xlsx')
>
> df.test <- iris[1:5, ]
>
> wb <- createWorkbook()
>
> sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, 'Indirect Sales')
>
> addPicture('trend_indirect.png' ,sheet1)
>
> addDataFrame(df.test ,sheet1, startRow=22)
>
> saveWorkbook(wb, file="stack_test.xlsx")

The image is just a simple ggplot graph saved in png. Thanks

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing libxtst.  That solved a similar problem for me.

I also installed fontconfig and libcups in the course of solving my issue, in case it wasn't libxtst that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same exception but running a Java program using Ubuntu 12.

I've installed libxtst6 and add this java parameter to my JAVA_OPTS variable: -Djava.awt.headless=true

Then it works fine.