# R xlsx error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.java2d.Disposer

Tags: java, r

I'm using the xlsx package to write Excel files in R:

```
library('xlsx')

df.test <- iris[1:5, ]

wb <- createWorkbook()

sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, 'Indirect Sales')

addPicture('trend_indirect.png' ,sheet1)

addDataFrame(df.test ,sheet1, startRow=22)

saveWorkbook(wb, file="stack_test.xlsx")
```

When I get to the  addPicture I get the following error:

> addDataFrame(df.test ,sheet1, startRow=22)
>   Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Z", "hasField", .jcast(x, "java/lang/Object"),  : 
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.java2d.Disposer

R version 2.15.2, 32bit. The image is just a simple ggplot graph saved in png. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this:

[Error writing xlsx in R: Could not initialize class sun.java2d.Disposer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144837/error-writing-xlsx-in-r-could-not-initialize-class-sun-java2d-disposer/16091526#16091526)

Try installing libxtst, and maybe fontconfig and libcups if that doesn't do it.